How to Connect Node.js Web Application to SQL Server Database Requiring VPN Access?
I'm trying to connect my web application to my SQL Server database, but I am facing a challenge. My database is hosted on a physical server within my corporation, and my web application is hosted on a third-party cloud server where I cannot make any changes to the server configuration, only deploy my application.
The problem is that I need to connect to the database using the "mssql" library with Node.js, but the connection requires a VPN, and my web application doesn't have VPN access like we do as users. How can I establish this connection under these constraints?
So far, I have tried configuring the "mssql" library in my Node.js application to connect to the SQL Server database, but it fails because the connection requires a VPN. I expected that there might be a way to either establish a VPN connection programmatically or configure a secure tunnel that my web application could use to communicate with the database server, but I haven't found a viable solution yet.

Host an API at the business instead, which can be connected to externally (though you may want to only allow permitted IP's), call the API from the web app, and that API will run the appropriate statements
